# BG image with Swing without overriding paintComponent

Tags: java, image, background, jframe, jpanel

I'm currently designing a menu with several screens with multiple buttons on each screen. To use buttons on top of the background image, which is in a jLabel (by default, I can't put buttons on TOP of the jLabel), I used GridBagLayout with two panels/menu screen, one panel containing the buttons (opaque = false) and one panel with the background image, or jLabel. In order to switch the current panels being displayed, depending on where the user is in the menu, I made each menu screen (aka. every 2 panels) in separate methods, not classes.

Now, I've come to the point where I'm working on parts of the interface that are unnecessarily complicated, and I don't feel GridBag will serve my purposes, so I was wondering if there was a different way to draw my background image, still being able to use my buttons on top of the image.

The most popular way I looked up was overriding the paintComponent method, but I can't do that, since I've made my JPanels in separate methods, not classes. They're all contained in my original JFrame.

Help would be greatly appreciated, thank you!

Just added this code, but my background remains white for some reason? Trying the other suggestion right now, thanks guys!

```
private void mainPanel() {

    icon = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/phantasma/menuv1.png"));
mainContainer1 = new javax.swing.JPanel() {
        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            g.drawImage(icon.getImage(), 0,0, null);
            super.paintComponent(g);
        }
    };
```

Comment: Why can't you override paintComponet? I don't see anything above which convinces me that it cannot be done in your program. You can always create an anonymous inner JPanel-derived class and override the paintComponent method there if need be.

Comment: Again as per my comment, you should call the `super.paintComponent()` method as the first call of  your paintComponent override. Else you may erase all that was drawn before.

Comment: @user962797, Why are you doing custom painting? Your question was about painting an image WITHOUT overriding paintComponent(). Did you not read my comment? Why would you not use a component that does the painting for you? Why reinvent the wheel when you don't need to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my comment above I state:

> You can always create an anonymous inner JPanel-derived class and override the paintComponent method there if need be.

As an example of what I mean, you can override paintComponent in any JPanel that you create whether it's derived from a stand-alone class or created within a method.  For e.g.,

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;

import javax.swing.*;

public class AnonInnerPanel {

   private static void createAndShowGui() {
      JPanel mainPanel = new JPanel() {
         @Override
         protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
         }

         @Override
         public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return new Dimension(300, 200);
         }
      };

      JFrame frame = new JFrame("AnonInnerPanel");
      frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
      frame.getContentPane().add(mainPanel);
      frame.pack();
      frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
      frame.setVisible(true);
   }

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
         public void run() {
            createAndShowGui();
         }
      });
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! had no idea you could do that, I'm sure it's obvious I'm new to programming :). I still have an issue though, after that, for some reason, my background remains white after this. EDIT: lol k

Comment: Post code as an edit to your original post, not in a comment where its unreadable. Also have a look at camickr's suggestion as it's probably better than mine. I'd up-vote it, but I'm out of votes! Also, you should probably call the `super.paintComponent(g)` on the first line of your method, else it may erase everything drawn.

Comment: If I can't get this to work after a bit, I'll try the other suggestion, but I'm using a builder for the basic layout, since I'm really bad at doing LayoutManager stuff strictly by code, lol. Yeah, I switched the paintComponent call to the first line, still showing up white, trying other stuff at the moment. Thanks for the continued assistance.

Comment: thanks again! works perfectly now, so awesome you can override like that :O

Answer (score 2):

> BG image with Swing without overriding paintComponent

I have no idea why all the postings suggest doing custom painting for this. You would only do custom painting if you need to automatically scale the background image.

If you want the image painted at its real size then use a JLabel.

> I can't put buttons on TOP of the jLabel),

Sure you can. Just set a LayoutManager for the JLabel and then you can add any component to it the same way you add components to a panel.

Comment: Now that my votes have been re-charged I can up-vote your post. Again this is the better answer.

Comment: I may try this later, but I'll have to learn a lot about manually coding Layout Manager stuff. gridbag is easy enough, but idk about the group layout stuff, lol. Thanks again both of you!

Comment: Using a JLabel is no different than using a JPanel. Whatever code you use to add components to the panel will be the same for the label. The only difference is that by default JPanel uses a FlowLayout. So you may need to add a `label.setLayout( new FlowLayout() );`